# Make view with tableview as its subview a gradient color

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit, gradient

I can make the view a background gradient without the tableview. When I add the tableview, I can either have the gradient view without the tableview cells visible or the tableview cells are visible with a white background. I cannot present the tableview with the cells visible and the gradient visible "underneath" it as the background.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    configureTableView()
    setGradientBackground()
}

func setGradientBackground() {
    let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 83/255, green: 187/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 64/255, green: 109/255, blue: 164/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
                
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
    gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
            
    tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at:0)
}

private func configureTableView() {
    tableView.register(NavigationMenuTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "menu")
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.separatorStyle = .none
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
}



class NavigationMenuTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

private let label = UILabel()

func setup(_ buttonName: String) {
    label.text = buttonName
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)
    label.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    label.clipsToBounds = true
    label.textColor = .white
    label.textAlignment = .center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(displayP3Red: 50/255, green: 96/255, blue: 149/255, alpha: 1)
    contentView.addSubview(label)
    label.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 3, width: contentView.frame.width - 40, height: contentView.frame.height - 6)
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you want the gradient to move as you scroll the table, or do you want it to stay put and just be visible through the cells?

Comment: Can you show the code where you try to set the background color of the cells?

Comment: I just want it to stay put. The tableview will not be scrollable.

Comment: "I cannot present the tableview with the cells visible and the gradient visible "underneath" it as the background."  So what's the question?

Comment: I want to see the gradient underneath the tableview cells. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You should create a separate view and set it as `backgroundView` for `tableView`.
In my case with `collectionView` it helped.

```
final class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        setGradientBackground()
    }

    private func setGradientBackground() {
        let colorTop =  UIColor(red: 83/255, green: 187/255, blue: 204/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
        let colorBottom = UIColor(red: 64/255, green: 109/255, blue: 164/255, alpha: 1.0).cgColor


        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorTop, colorBottom]
        gradientLayer.locations = [0.0, 1.0]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds

        let backgroundView = UIView(frame: collectionView.bounds)
        backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: .zero)
        collectionView.backgroundView = backgroundView
    }

}


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 100
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath)
        cell.backgroundColor = .white
        return cell
    }
}
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C3gsX.png)